# How to reshape a multidimensional array to a 2D image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I'm working on an array shaped as follows

```
(64, 1, 64, 64)
```

This is in fact one grayscale image that was split into 64 patches, each patch with 64*64px.

Now I need to rebuild it into a 512*512px image.

I've tried using

```
np.reshape(arr, (512, 512))
```

but of course the resulting image is not as expected.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how your patches are arranged. But the first thing you could try is

```
image.reshape(8, 8, 64, 64).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(512, 512)
```

This is assuming that the original zeroth dimension lists the patches row by row, i.e. 0-7 are the first row of patches from left to right, 8-15 the second row and so on.

The first reshape reestablishes that arrangement, after it choosing index i, j for axes 0 and 1 addresses the j+1st patch in the i+1st row.

Now comes the interesting bit: When merging axes by reshape:

- only adjacent dimensions can be combined
- all but the rightmost axis in each block will be dispersed

Since we want to keep each patch together we have to rearrange in such a way that the current axes 2 and 3 become the rightmost members of blocks. That is what the `swapaxes` does.

By now the shape is (8, 64, 8, 64) and axes 1 and 3 are the within-patch coordinates. Combining two pairs `( 8, 64 -> 512     8, 64 -> 512 )` is all that's left to do.

Comment: You nailed it, thanks so much, it would take me days to figure out that reshaping jiujitsu... :)

Comment: Just an educated guess ;-) I'll try and add a bit of explanation to the post.