# Merge array of Matrixs into one Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I will try to be as clear as possible.

I'm trying to implement an LBP (local binary pattern) algorithm.

The basic global version of my implementation work good. I run my algorithm in this way:

```
img = Image.open("path/of/my/image.png").convert("L") # read the image
lbpObject = LBP( numpy.array(img) ) #pass the numpy array of the img
lbpObject.execute()
result = lbpObject.getImageArray()
```

**result** contain a matrix in gray scale with correct value (I've done a lot test, trust me)

I use LBP in order to implement Face Recognition, so I use that data to perform SVM classification.
But using global version of this algorithm I get a very low accuracy. 
So I'm trying to perform a multi-block LBP.

```
img = Image.open("path/of/my/image.png").convert("L") # read the image
imgArray = numpy.array(img)
# Create blocks 16*16 of the original image
shaped = imgArray.reshape(16, 16, -1)
xBlocks = []

#perform LBP for each block and store the value on xBlocks
for s in shaped:
    lbpObject = LBP(s)
    lbpObject.execute()
    xBlock.append(lbpObject.getImageArray())
```

Now xBlock is a vector of matrix with the value that I need. 
How can I marge all values into one matrix like the first result variable?

Ps: LBP is my class.

Comment: Take a look at this- [How to reshape a multidimensional array to a 2D image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441230/how-to-reshape-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-2d-image)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work-

```
L=np.array(xBlock)
image=L.reshape((16,16,np.shape(imgArray)[0]/16,-1)).swapaxes(1,2).reshape((np.shape(imgArray)[0],-1))
```

I got some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441230/how-to-reshape-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-2d-image)